# Training Tesseract - Failed Loading Trained Language

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I try to train language for tesseract. I'm using Tess4J for OCR process. I use jTessBoxEditor and SerakTesseractTrainer for training operation. After I prepare my traindata, I put it at Tesseract/tessdata and Tess4j/tessdata folder.

Then, I set new language like this:

```
    Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
    tesseract.setLanguage("custom");
```

After I execute program, I get this error:

```
Error opening data file ./tessdata/custom.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'custom'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
```

I check my folders; `custom.traineddata` is in tess4j/tessdata and tesseract/tessdata folder. I have other languages that are working fine. I don't know why it can't find new language data?  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to add an answer, *actually add an answer* by answering your own question.

Comment: If your problem solve kindly add answer or delete your question.

Comment: I add an answer and remove edit part from my question.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue:

I have to add `custom.traineddata` to myproject/tessdata folder. After adding, it works.

Comment: Thanks for doing that.